# Sandbox/Confine HTML Code in DIV tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Currently i am working on a plugin and widget based CMS.

A widget is a html/javasctript code snippet which always resides in a main div (say it widget div) element.

Using jquery and jquery-ui as javascript framework.

**My Question:**

How can we confine/sandbox html of the widget in the containing div so that if there is any improper html which can break layout of all the page can be avoided?

**---- EDIT ----**

OK i got an idea, is it feasible/possible on server side ?

1. read the widget html from widget file
2. check if it is proper html or not (using some html parser library).
3. Fix it and past in template.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot i think you should include this in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we confine/sandbox html of the
>   widget in the containing div so that
>   if there **is any improper html which
>   can break layout of all the page** can
>   be avoided?

If you need to do it robustly, the only choice is to use an `iframe`.

If the widget HTML contained something like:

```
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

That's going to break any page (that uses `div`s, so in other words: all pages).

---

From a now deleted comment:

> Regarding your update, that should
>   work. One of [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php),
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php,
>   or [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) should be what you're
>   looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Assuming proper HTML, you can give it a fixed height and width, set overflow to hidden, scroll or auto, and set position to relative to stop the CSS breaking the layout.

Nothing client side, however, could prevent a widget from (for example) having an extra `</div>` to close the container prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

as Quentin already said and explained, this isn't possible.

if you want to be sure a widget can't affect other parts of your website, you'll have to put it into an `iframe` (wich seems to be [common practice](http://www.google.de/#q=html+widget+iframe)).